# Simplifying a set of constraints with sympy by removing variables

Tags: python, constraints, sympy

I'm currently writing a simplification tool for another software project and I want to simplify some math.

I have a given a set of equations and inequalities like

```
x = a
y + 1 = b
x = y
z = c
y > z
```

I want to get a set of simplified equations and inequalities with preferably less variables
of the set `S={x,y,z}` and somehow normalized to 0 on one side of the equation

```
0 = b - (a + 1)
0 > c - b + 1
```

So the variables in `S` act as intermediate storage, or connections between the variables `{a,b,c}`.

- all variables and constants can be considered integer
- it is ok if no such simplification exists
- the result does not need to be optimal
- if this works for non linear equations too it would be a plus but is not a must
- I'm ok with using other python libraries than sympy
- I want to have a general approach, the given constraints are just an example, I do not know the structure of the equations in advance

I tried to read into sympy.solve, sympy.simplify and sympy.reduce_inequalities.

- I didn't manage to get simplify to work on a set of constraints instead of a single expression.
- solve seems to be only able to handle equalities, and not also inequalities. Also I dont think i want to solve these equations, but rather remove variables.
- reduce_inequalities seems to be restricted to only one variable. I'm not sure how to execute this function only for one variable at a time s.t. it also considers the equations.

I do not need complete source code but a rough approach how to tackle this problem or if it is at all feasible with sympy.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that I would potentially approach this would be to use a Groebner basis. I would introduce a new symbol `t` and a new equation `t = y - z` so that the inequality becomes `t > 0` (which we will remember separately). Then the system is converted into only equations:

```
In [6]: a, b, c, t, x, y, z = symbols('a, b, c, t, x, y, z')

In [7]: eqs = [Eq(x, a), Eq(y+1, b), Eq(x, y), Eq(z, c), Eq(y - z, t)]

In [8]: eqs
Out[8]: [x = a, y + 1 = b, x = y, z = c, y - z = t]
```

Now you can compute a Groebner basis (note that the order of the symbols matters):

```
In [20]: gb = groebner(eqs, [x, y, z, t, a, b, c])

In [21]: for p in gb: pprint(Eq(p, 0))
-b + x + 1 = 0
-b + y + 1 = 0
-c + z = 0
-b + c + t + 1 = 0
a - b + 1 = 0
```

The final two equations not involving x, y, z are what you want. The equation having `t` can be solved for `t` to recover the inequality:

```
In [25]: S(0) < solve(gb[3], t)[0]
Out[25]: 0 < b - c - 1

In [26]: Eq(0, gb[4])
Out[26]: 0 = a - b + 1
```

More generally the approach here is:

- Compute a Groebner basis with a symbol ordering that first lists the symbols that you want to eliminate (x, y, z), then the dummy symbols (t), and then the symbols that you want to keep (a, b, c).
- Discard the first however many polynomials from the basis that involve the symbols that you are not interested in.
- Solve the polynomials involving dummy variables like t to recover the inequalities.
- Treat the remaining polynomials as equations involving the symbols of interest.

Computing a Groebner basis can be extremely expensive for more complicated polynomial inputs so whether or not this approach is practical does depend on the complexity of the conditions that you start with. If all conditions are linear like in the examples then it will be fast.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is really helpful and I must admit that I never heard of Groebner bases. It will take me some time to implement. I have a few follow up questions.

1. Is there a way of telling which of the resulting polynomials contain only the symbols I want to keep (except by inspecting them) ?
2. Can it be ensured that there exists always a solution not containing any of `{x,y,z}` ?

Comment: You can use `p.has(x, y, z)` or `p.free_symbols` to test which symbols are in an expression. It is not guaranteed that there exists any solutions at all e.g. if your constraints have `x = 1` and `x = 2` then there are no possible values for any symbols that can satisfy this. In that case your Groebner basis will just be `[1]`.